# How to do userEvnt.click on a div in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

so i have a component that maps an array and returns a div with an onClick event

```
     {credits?.crew.slice(0, maxCreditsResults).map((crew, idx) => {
              return (
                <div
                  className='cast-card'
                  key={idx}
                  onClick={() => navigate(`/${EPages.person}/${crew.id}`)}
                >
                  <p>-{crew.name}</p>
                  <p>Department: {crew.department}</p>
                </div>
              );
            })}
```

i want to test this click event but i dont know how to get that specific div so i can click it with userEvent.click()

i looked at the methods of the sreen that comes from react testing library but i cant find one that would help me

Answer (score 0):

You can add data-testid like `<div data-testid = {idx + '-cast-card' }`
Then call first element of div.

```
const element = screen.getByTestId('0-cast-cart')
fireEvent.click(element);
```